# httpsサーバーへajax通信をする場合、通信内容は暗号化されているか

Tags: javascript, monaca, html5, ajax

httpsサーバーへajax通信をする場合（ajaxのurlパラメータに`https://example.com`を指定して通信する場合）、通信内容は全てssl暗号化されているという理解なのですが、それで正しいでしょうか。

Comment: urlパラメータという表現はクエリストリング全体を指すようにも読めるため、GETなのかPOSTなのか質問を明確にした方が良いと思います。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

はい、GETパラメータも暗号化されます。

POSTと異なる以下の点は留意すべきです。

- サーバ側のログにURLとして平文で残る場合が多い
- ブラウザ側の履歴(html5のタグがあるので、History API)に残る場合がある

本家にもよく似た[Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629222/are-querystring-parameters-secure-in-https-http-ssl)がありました。リファラーもURLが送信されることを考慮しなければなりませんが、ajaxであれば不要かと。後々漏れると困る気密性の高い情報はGETパラメータに流してはならず、極力POSTする方針が安全だと考えます（限定的な利用は除く）。

Comment: 早速のご回答誠にありがとうございます。
非常に細かい点で恐縮なのですが、GETのみならずPOSTでも暗号化されると書いていただいているように見えるのですが、その理解で間違いないでしょうか（今回は、POSTで利用したいと思っています）。

Comment: POSTのbodyはもちろん暗号化されます。

Comment: 非常によくわかりました。ありがとうございます。